# Accessing endpoint via SSH tunnel

Tags: javascript, axios, cross-domain, fetch-api, ssh-tunnel

I'm running a dev project on my local machine (localhost) which is trying to load data from an endpoint on a server via an SSH tunnel (a React JS SPA).

The SSH tunnel is established fine and the endpoint returns the correct data packet when run in Postman using a simple GET.

But when I try to access the data from my app (fetch and Axios tried) a 200 is returned but unfortunately always with an empty array - rather than a 1k object array.

Below are the 2 simple requests, where 'localhost:8912' is the exposed & mapped port - which works in Postman.

Fetch:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8912/ENDPOINT/")
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return null;
  });
```

Axios:

```
axios
  .get("http://localhost:8912/ENDPOINT/")
  .then(data => console.log(data.data))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return null;
  });
```

The result is returned almost immediately within the browser but take a few seconds within Postman due to server-side calculations.

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: Your Tunnel must tunnel to the api, not a frontend App

Comment: the tunnel isn't connected to a frontent app, it's connected to the api, the api is mapped to that localhost port and is working fine outside of the browser - i.e. I can hit all the end points from my local machine from within Postman etc and the api is returning 200 in the browser just without any data packet - as though the Promise is completing before the data is returned - which isn't the case outside of the browser.

Comment: What happens when you replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing **`localhost`** with **`127.0.0.1`**

This could be related to the address resolution in the browser vs. Postman.

Comment: I can't believe this actually worked - sometimes it's the simple things. Thanks @janniks

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a proxy you can combine axios with another npm library — [tunnel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tunnel) to establish a HTTPS-over-HTTP tunnel:

```
    import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
    import * as tunnel from 'tunnel';
    const agent = tunnel.httpsOverHttp({
        proxy: {
            host: 'proxy.mycorp.com',
            port: 8000,
        },
    });
    const axiosClient: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'https://some.api.com:443',  // here I specify port 443
        httpsAgent: agent,
    });
```

Ref: https://janmolak.com/node-js-axios-behind-corporate-proxies-8b17a6f31f9d

Answer (score -1):

```
fetch("http://localhost:8912/ENDPOINT/")
  .then(res => return res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    return null;
  });
```

fetch returns an object as Promise that contains various information like headers, HTTP status etc. etc.

You have res.json() and various other possibilities. .json() will just return the body as promise with json content.

For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

You can return the data as following:

- .arrayBuffer()
- .blob()
- .json()
- .text()
- .formData()